# Unreolved reference on import

Tags: python, random, pycharm

I'm trying to import the random module and it gets accused as "Unresolved reference" but random works, I only get this warning, and I already tried to click on the red lamp but it had nothing to help me, Print:

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUFHm.png)

Comment: Please give a [mcve], not an image of a screenshot that we are unable to reproduce.

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate cache and restart
And see if you still have the issue.